# I am receiving a versioning date error when trying to call the FourSquare API

Tags: api, foursquare

I am getting an error when trying to call on the Foursquare places API about my versioning being old, however the date specified in the error is much older than the date I am using. Am I missing something?

This is for a certification project, can someone please advise what's going on, I have not found any resources on this. I have tried versioning dates `20180604` and `20180323` and get the same error. I have attached my code.

```
CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxx'

CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxx'

VERSION = '20180604'

LIMIT = 30

Latitude = 38.925496298

Longitude = -77.0350515265
```

**And this is the error when I try and call results**

```
results = requests.get(url).json()

ERROR: 'meta': {'code': 410,
  'errorType': 'param_error',
  'errorDetail': 'The Foursquare API no longer supports requests that pass in a version v <= 20120609. For more details see https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning',
  'requestId': '5f4e58420179823aae7b5f91'},
 'response': {}}
```

Comment: Please show your `url` e.g. https://api.foursquare.com/v2/search...

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. If I have a future question on this sort of thing I will be sure to include the url.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. I am not sure why it wasn't before (the only thing I did differently was install Folium) but in any event it is now working. Sorry I can't offer more clarity around this. If others are having similar issues, I would try using a different environment. I was operating in IBM Watson Studio and switched to my local instance of Jupyter, confirmed it worked, then it worked when I went back to Watson. So I'm not sure, but that's what I can offer.